# How do I use a SQL function inside my SQL query

Tags: sql

Suppose that I have a SQL function called `MAGIC` that returns the magical value of a number.

Suppose further that I want to write a SQL query that will return a list of numbers from a SQL table along with their magical values.

My instinct is to write

```
SELECT number, MAGIC(number) FROM NUMBERS;
```

However, this returns the error message `MAGIC is not a recognized function name.  How can I make this work?

EDIT: It looks like MAGIC is set up to be a table-valued function even though it returns only a single value.  My DBA will not give me access to any database function code, so I have to work with it that way.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? MySQL? SQL Server?

Comment: Make it return a _single_ value.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Oded, it's coded by someone else to return the single value as a table and I cannot change that.  Is there an easy way extract the single value in my SQL code?

Answer (score 5):

If it is a scalar-value function, fully qualify your function in the TSQL:

```
SELECT number, dbo.MAGIC(number) FROM NUMBERS;
```

Comment: I already tried this. I get the following error message: Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.Fn_Org_GetAncestor", or the name is ambiguous.

Comment: You got error, because it search for Scalar-valued functions when you use it in this syntax.

Comment: For the error Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.Fn_Org_GetAncestor", or the name is ambiguous. If you restart SSMS that error might go away. I got this info from https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b3d9211d-7d4a-48e7-abc0-ef0a0f27e4ee/cannot-run-any-scalar-function-in-sql-server-2008-r2?forum=transactsql

Answer (score 1):

If its a table-valued function, then just do this:

```
SELECT n.number, mn.number FROM numbers as n CROSS JOIN dbo.Magic(n.number) as mn
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the function like a field... this is for TSQL.

```
SELECT number,
-- start function
(SELECT function_field_name FROM dbo.MAGIC(number)) AS magic_number
-- end function 
FROM dbo.NUMBERS
```